# Pinescript - Syminfo.type undeclared identifier

Tags: pine-script

I dont understand why pinescript wont let me use the syminfo.type variable. Documentation for version 4 says it should support it.

I am trying to just do a check on the type of the security and only plot if it is a security of type futures. I am just trying to mark the real trading hours session.

```
//version 4
study("RTH Vertical Lines", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)
type = syminfo.type
condOpen = (syminfo.timezone == 'America/Chicago') and (hour == 8 and minute == 30) and type == "futures"
condClose = (syminfo.timezone == 'America/Chicago') and (hour == 15 and minute == 0) and type == "futures"

plot(condOpen ? 10e20 : na, style = histogram, color=#FFFF00, transp=60)
plot(condClose ? 10e20 : na, style = histogram, color=#FFFF00, transp=60)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `syminfo.type`, but you forgot the `@` character for the version number, so the compiler didn't use version 4, and doesn't recognize it.

```
//@version=4
study("RTH Vertical Lines", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

var bool    typeOk      = syminfo.type     == "futures"
var bool    timezoneOk  = syminfo.timezone == "America/Chicago"

condOpen  = timezoneOk and (hour ==  8 and minute == 30) and typeOk
condClose = timezoneOk and (hour == 15 and minute ==  0) and typeOk

plot(condOpen  ? 10e20 : na, style = plot.style_histogram, color=color.yellow, transp=60)
plot(condClose ? 10e20 : na, style = plot.style_histogram, color=color.yellow, transp=60)
```

You could also use `bgcolor()` to mark your open/close bars, instead of `plot()`.
This way, you don't need the `scale.none` in `study()`

```
//@version=4
study("RTH Vertical Lines", overlay=true)

var bool    typeOk      = syminfo.type     == "futures"
var bool    timezoneOk  = syminfo.timezone == "America/Chicago"

condOpen  = timezoneOk and (hour ==  8 and minute == 30) and typeOk
condClose = timezoneOk and (hour == 15 and minute ==  0) and typeOk

bgcolor(condOpen  ? color.blue : na, transp=60)
bgcolor(condClose ? color.blue : na, transp=60)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a huge help!!!
Follow up question, 
1.) Do you know why I had to use the 8:30 vs 9:30 or the 15:00 vs 16:00? 
2.) Do you know what the 10e20 was doing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `1.)`. About `2.)`, it just plots a very big value, which makes it look like a vertical line. 10e20 is a 10 with 20 zeroes added.